# ER model not producing NULL values with LEFT OUTER JOIN in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have been working on a database for reviewing movies and have tried to complete a LEFT OUTER JOIN to which the results of the query end with NULL values where certain movies were not reviewed by certain critics.  I have had to use cross join in order to multiply the rows by each other, however, I should be getting the results from the LEFT OUTER JOIN by itself.

```
mysql> select *
-> from F;
+------------+--------------------------------+-------------+----------------    -----+-----------+
| FilmNumber | FilmName                       | OpeningDate | TopBilledActor      | Genre     |
+------------+--------------------------------+-------------+----------------    -----+-----------+
| F1         | Transformers: The Last Knight  | 6/21/2017   | Mark Wahlberg       | Action    |
| F2         | Cars 3                         | 6/16/2017   | Owen Wilson         | Animation |
| F3         | Wonder Woman                   | 6/2/2017    | Gal Gadot           | Action    |
| F4         | All Eyez on Me                 | 6/16/2017   | Demetrius Shipp Jr. | Biography |
| F5         | The Mummy                      | 6/9/2017    | Tom Cruise          | Action    |
| F6         | Rough Night                    | 6/16/2017   | Scarlett Johansson  | Comedy    |
| F7         | Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2 | 5/5/2017    | Chris Pratt         | Action    |
| F8         | Men Tell No Tales              | 5/26/2017   | Johnny Depp         | Action    |
| F9         | 47 Meters Down                 | 6/16/2017   | Mandy Moore         | Adventure |
| F10        | Captain Underpants             | 6/2/2017    | Kevin Hart          | Animation |
+------------+--------------------------------+-------------+----------------    -----+-----------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select *
-> from C;
+------------------+----------------------+-----------------+
| CriticSiteNumber | CriticSiteName       | CriticName      |
+------------------+----------------------+-----------------+
| C1               | The New York Times   | Neil Genzlinger |
| C2               | Variety              | Owen Gleiberman |
| C3               | Variety              | Andrew Barker   |
| C4               | IndieWire            | Judy Dry        |
| C5               | IndieWire            | Eric Kohn       |
| C6               | Paste Magazine       | Tim Grierson    |
| C7               | We Got This Covered  | Matt Donato     |
| C8               | Entertainment Weekly | Chris Nashawty  |
+------------------+----------------------+-----------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
mysql> select *
    -> from FC;
+------------+------------------+--------------+
| FilmNumber | CriticSiteNumber | OverallScore |
+------------+------------------+--------------+
| F1         | C1               |           50 |
| F1         | C2               |           60 |
| F1         | C5               |           50 |
| F1         | C6               |           20 |
| F1         | C7               |           40 |
| F1         | C8               |           58 |
| F2         | C1               |           80 |
| F2         | C2               |           70 |
| F2         | C5               |           83 |
| F2         | C6               |           50 |
| F2         | C7               |           60 |
| F3         | C1               |           80 |
| F3         | C2               |           82 |
| F3         | C3               |           78 |
| F3         | C4               |           72 |
| F3         | C6               |           81 |
| F3         | C8               |           85 |
| F4         | C1               |           20 |
| F4         | C2               |           60 |
| F4         | C4               |           58 |
| F4         | C6               |           42 |
| F5         | C2               |           50 |
| F5         | C4               |           16 |
| F5         | C6               |           52 |
| F5         | C7               |           30 |
| F5         | C8               |           67 |
| F6         | C1               |           40 |
| F6         | C2               |           70 |
| F6         | C3               |           65 |
| F6         | C5               |           83 |
| F6         | C6               |           43 |
| F6         | C7               |           70 |
| F6         | C8               |           58 |
| F7         | C2               |           70 |
| F7         | C5               |           67 |
| F7         | C6               |           80 |
| F7         | C7               |           80 |
| F7         | C8               |           67 |
| F8         | C3               |           38 |
| F8         | C4               |           51 |
| F8         | C6               |           22 |
| F8         | C7               |           58 |
| F8         | C8               |           45 |
| F9         | C1               |           55 |
| F9         | C2               |           44 |
| F9         | C4               |           50 |
| F9         | C6               |           70 |
| F9         | C7               |           60 |
| F9         | C8               |           67 |
| F10        | C1               |           69 |
| F10        | C2               |           60 |
| F10        | C4               |           55 |
| F10        | C7               |           70 |
| F10        | C8               |           83 |
+------------+------------------+--------------+
54 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Since these are my tables, you will notice that there are many instances where films were not given scores by certain critics, but when I perform a LEFT OUTER JOIN, as shown by my professor, these are my results:

The results I am trying to obtain are results where in the OverallScore column, there would be a NULL value for every instance there wasn't a review done by a certain critic.  In other words, I want to see 80 total rows (10 films, 8 critics) without having to use a CROSS JOIN or NULL in the query.

```
    mysql> select F.FilmName, FC.CriticSiteNumber, FC.OverallScore
    -> from F LEFT OUTER JOIN FC
    -> on F.FilmNumber=FC.FilmNumber
    -> order by FilmName;
+--------------------------------+------------------+--------------+
| FilmName                       | CriticSiteNumber | OverallScore |
+--------------------------------+------------------+--------------+
| 47 Meters Down                 | C1               |           55 |
| 47 Meters Down                 | C2               |           44 |
| 47 Meters Down                 | C4               |           50 |
| 47 Meters Down                 | C6               |           70 |
| 47 Meters Down                 | C7               |           60 |
| 47 Meters Down                 | C8               |           67 |
| All Eyez on Me                 | C1               |           20 |
| All Eyez on Me                 | C2               |           60 |
| All Eyez on Me                 | C4               |           58 |
| All Eyez on Me                 | C6               |           42 |
| Captain Underpants             | C1               |           69 |
| Captain Underpants             | C2               |           60 |
| Captain Underpants             | C4               |           55 |
| Captain Underpants             | C7               |           70 |
| Captain Underpants             | C8               |           83 |
| Cars 3                         | C1               |           80 |
| Cars 3                         | C2               |           70 |
| Cars 3                         | C5               |           83 |
| Cars 3                         | C6               |           50 |
| Cars 3                         | C7               |           60 |
| Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2 | C2               |           70 |
| Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2 | C5               |           67 |
| Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2 | C6               |           80 |
| Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2 | C7               |           80 |
| Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2 | C8               |           67 |
| Men Tell No Tales              | C3               |           38 |
| Men Tell No Tales              | C4               |           51 |
| Men Tell No Tales              | C6               |           22 |
| Men Tell No Tales              | C7               |           58 |
| Men Tell No Tales              | C8               |           45 |
| Rough Night                    | C1               |           40 |
| Rough Night                    | C2               |           70 |
| Rough Night                    | C3               |           65 |
| Rough Night                    | C5               |           83 |
| Rough Night                    | C6               |           43 |
| Rough Night                    | C7               |           70 |
| Rough Night                    | C8               |           58 |
| The Mummy                      | C2               |           50 |
| The Mummy                      | C4               |           16 |
| The Mummy                      | C6               |           52 |
| The Mummy                      | C7               |           30 |
| The Mummy                      | C8               |           67 |
| Transformers: The Last Knight  | C1               |           50 |
| Transformers: The Last Knight  | C2               |           60 |
| Transformers: The Last Knight  | C5               |           50 |
| Transformers: The Last Knight  | C6               |           20 |
| Transformers: The Last Knight  | C7               |           40 |
| Transformers: The Last Knight  | C8               |           58 |
| Wonder Woman                   | C1               |           80 |
| Wonder Woman                   | C2               |           82 |
| Wonder Woman                   | C3               |           78 |
| Wonder Woman                   | C4               |           72 |
| Wonder Woman                   | C6               |           81 |
| Wonder Woman                   | C8               |           85 |
+--------------------------------+------------------+--------------+
54 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Where's the `LEFT OUTER JOIN`? There isn't one in the query that's giving you wrong results.

Comment: My mistake I copied the wrong query:

Comment: The correct one is now posted at the end

Comment: Any luck with the answer I posted below?

Comment: unfortunately no it did not.  The results were the exact same results from the previous query.

Comment: Do you think potentially it could have something to do with the keys or how the tables are implemented? I have asked a few people who seem to believe that a LEFT OUTER JOIN when implemented correctly which I believe you have, should (in my case) produce NULL values in the OverallScore section where certain movies were not rated.  I am also wondering if when I created the tables, the portions that where there were no reviews, should a NULL value have been implemented in those areas.....I am really stuck to find an answer.

Comment: Looking at it again, it might be because you're selecting FC.CriticSiteNumber, instead of C.CriticSiteNumber. The FC table only has CriticSiteNumbers that actually have reviews. Try the query in my edited answer.

Comment: Ya I tried that too and still I am getting the same results. I believe that’s why I have only had success when I use a cross join and multiply the F and C tables together giving my the truest number of rows I needed. I am continuously wondering if I implemented the tables wrong. I know that in the FC table,the FilmNumber and the CriticSiteNumber are both foreign keys with references to the F and C tables but I truly don’t know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you're not including the C table in your query. So the query doesn't pull up any `NULL` values because you're only joining the F table on the FC table. The engine doesn't know that you want to include all the critics in the result, basically. Try this:

```
mysql> select F.FilmName, C.CriticSiteNumber, FC.OverallScore
-> from F LEFT OUTER JOIN FC
-> on F.FilmNumber=FC.FilmNumber
-> LEFT OUTER JOIN C
-> ON C.CriticSiteNumber = FC.CriticSiteNumber
-> order by FilmName;
```